# Shortcut to open resource search in PyCharm

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pycharm

In Eclipse I'm very used to the Command+R key that opens up a project search box that does a Find-As-You-Type on a file name.

So to jump from one file in a project to any other file, it's as simple as:
1. Command+R
2. Type the first few letters of the name
3. Return

I'm new to PyCharm and having trouble finding this behavior? I'd be surprised if it's not here somewhere, but I'm not seeing the keyboard shortcut...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Navigate` | `File...` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>).

Answer (score 5):

On a mac the key shortcut is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the keymap in PyCharm to your preferred keys combination. To do this, Go to Pycharm->Preferences->KeyMap (under IDE Settings)